# Execute stored procedure from multiple threads in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, threadpool, connection-pooling

I need to execute a stored procedure from c# code (.net 3.5, EF 1) for an array of values. So I tought it would be ok to use `ConnectionPool` and `ThreadPool`. Here is my code:

```
DBModel db;

private void generateInvoices(Object retailers)
{
    List<my_db_view> ret = (List<my_db_view>)retailers;

    foreach (my_db_view retailer in ret)
    {
        try
        {
            tblMyItem accDoc = db.pi_ami_add_my_item(retailer.RetailerID, retailer.ContractID, retailer.fru_code, null).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //handle exception
        }
    }
}

private void export(DBModel db)
{
    this.db = db;
    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(10, 10);
    ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(50, 50);
    //both methods returned true
    List<my_db_view> retailers = db.my_db_view.ToList();
    while (retailers.Count > 0)
    {
        int count = Math.Min(5, retailers.Count);
        List<my_db_view> toProcess = new List<my_db_view>();
        toProcess.AddRange(retailers.Take(count));
        retailers.RemoveRange(0, count);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(generateInvoices), toProcess);
    }

    int availableThreads;
    int maxthreads, q, w;

    ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out availableThreads, out q);
    ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out maxthreads, out w);
    while (availableThreads != maxthreads)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("there are {0} threds active", (maxthreads - availableThreads));
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out availableThreads, out q);
        ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out maxthreads, out w);
    }
    //some code
}
```

My connection string:

```
Data Source=192.168.0.1\SQL;Initial Catalog=MY_DATABASE;User id=user;Password=pass;Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=60;Max Pool Size=100;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

My questions:

1. After I call `db.pi_ami_add_my_item`, when this line is executed, the connection will be closed?
2. Why I've got the error

   > The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting.

   when I was running my code, when the minimum connections was set to 60 and max threads in the pool was set to 50?
3. How EF manages connections when using the same database model object from multiple threads?

My problem is execution time. I need to execute my stored procedure of 200.000 times in less than 30 minutes. Given the stored procedure complexity, it's very hard to adapt it to use a set based approach. I've noticed that it runs faster if I use threads.

Comment: unless very specific cases it is way better to let the SQL Server to handle concurrency for us, it has been designed for that! you do need to care about connection pool and thread pool, just have a loop in which you call n times the sproc with the proper parameters, you can probably always use the same connection. SQL Server will handle load and concurrency for you.

Comment: First, *why* do you want to run stored procedures concurrently, particularly from an ORM like EF? What is the *real* problem you are trying to solve? If you are trying to emulate bulk operations, ORMs are unsuitable. Second, assuming DbModel is your context, it manages a single connection so you are effectively trying to open and use the same connection from multiple threads. Even if you used multiple models, you would hurt performance, not improve it. Each request causes latency and delays. You need to batch multiple operations together and execute them as a single request to the server

Comment: My problem is execution time. I need to execute my stored procedure of 200.000 times in less than 30 minutes. Given the stored procedure complexity, it's very hard to adapt it to use a set based approach. I've noticed that it runs faster if i use threads